# Function getauxval is undefined in Android Studio

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-native-library

So I'm trying to use the getauxval function in a native library I write in Android Studio,
but unfortunately I can't compile the code since the function seems to don't exist.

When I include the header auxv.h where the function defined I can find the function there with the condition macros:

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 18

unsigned long int getauxval(unsigned long int __type) __INTRODUCED_IN(18);

#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 18 */
```

My Android api variable is bigger than 18, and anyway I tried to edit and remove this condition macro and it still didn't work... does anyone know how to fix it?
Thank you!